# WSO2 Developer Portal API: map-keys endpoint does not work

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm migrating from WSO2 2.6 over to WSO2 4.1.
So far faced with an issue that I can not import consumerKey and consumerSecret using DevPortl API.
My import flow looks like this:

Application created thru API in the following way (where {{basepath}} is https://{host}/api/am/devportal/v2.1):

Endpoint: `POST {{basepath}}/applications`

Request:

```
{
  "name": "Testing import",
  "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
  "description": "Test description",
  "tokenType": "JWT"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "applicationId": "79d77586-4f5f-4ea6-8260-2c59188e423c",
    "name": "Testing import",
    "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited",
    "description": "Test description",
    "tokenType": "JWT",
    "status": "APPROVED",
    "groups": [],
    "subscriptionCount": 0,
    "keys": [],
    "attributes": {},
    "subscriptionScopes": [],
    "owner": "CARCTEMY/apiuser",
    "hashEnabled": null
}
```

After that for the newly created application I'm invoking `POST {{basepath}}/applications/79d77586-4f5f-4ea6-8260-2c59188e423c/map-keys` with consumerKey and consumerSecret created in WSO2 2.6 version:

```
{
  "consumerKey": "KBs51iQITZK02v5oPwSRewK7q_Qa",
  "consumerSecret": "Qt2u7INdReROhpPI8nbedyDBOIYa",
  "keyManager": "Resident Key Manager",
  "keyType": "PRODUCTION"
}
```

and as a response I'm getting following error:

```
{
    "code": 900967,
    "message": "General Error",
    "description": "Server Error Occurred",
    "moreInfo": "",
    "error": []
}
```

Logs are attached below.

As far as I understand from logs KeyManager requires some additional authentication steps, but at the same time I can generate key and secret thru `POST {{basepath}}/applications/{applicationId}/generate-keys` endpoint, thus that 401 error confuses me. Also, if I first run /generate-keys and then /map-keys the second request returns me an error saying "Key Mappings already exists"

Am I missing some additional configs for KeyManager?

**UPD**

I've also tried to call `/map-keys` endpoint as a WSO admin user with consumerKey and consumerSecret generated by another instance of WSO2 v4.1 but got the same error. Bearer token generated with following scopes: *apim:admin apim:api_key apim:app_import_export apim:app_manage apim:store_settings apim:sub_alert_manage apim:sub_manage apim:subscribe apim:subscribe apim:api_view apim:api_create apim:api_publish apim:tier_view*

However, at the same time `/generate-keys` endpoint work.
So I assume that `/map-keys` is broken or requires some additional scopes I'm not aware of.

---

http_acces.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2023:18:35:10 +0200] POST /api/am/devportal/v2.1/applications/79d77586-4f5f-4ea6-8260-2c59188e423c/map-keys HTTP/1.1 500 104 - PostmanRuntime/7.30.1 0.029
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2023:18:35:10 +0200] GET /keymanager-operations/dcr/register/S0JzNTFpUUlUWkswMnY1b1B3U1Jld0s3cV9RYQ%3D%3D HTTP/1.1 401 - - Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.18) 0.009
```

wso2-apigw-errors.log:

```
2023-02-13T18:35:10,942 [-] [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-21] ERROR AbstractKeyManager Some thing went wrong while getting OAuth application for given consumer key KBs51iQITZK02v5oPwSRewK7q_Qa
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 401 Reason: 
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:42) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:35) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100) ~[io.github.openfeign.feign-core_11.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy467.getApplication(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.mapOAuthApplication_aroundBody20(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:581) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.mapOAuthApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:561) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.mapExistingOAuthClient_aroundBody78(APIConsumerImpl.java:2517) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.mapExistingOAuthClient(APIConsumerImpl.java:2452) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdMapKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:1101) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdMapKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:281) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[?:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.4.52.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.58.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
2023-02-13T18:35:10,942 [-] [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-21] ERROR GlobalThrowableMapper Some thing went wrong while getting OAuth application for given consumer key KBs51iQITZK02v5oPwSRewK7q_Qa
```

wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2023-02-13 18:35:10,942] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager} - Some thing went wrong while getting OAuth application for given consumer key KBs51iQITZK02v5oPwSRewK7q_Qa org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 401 Reason: 
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:42)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:35)
    at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy467.getApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.mapOAuthApplication_aroundBody20(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:581)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.mapOAuthApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:561)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.mapExistingOAuthClient_aroundBody78(APIConsumerImpl.java:2517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.mapExistingOAuthClient(APIConsumerImpl.java:2452)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdMapKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:1101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdMapKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:281)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

TID: [-1234] [api/am/devportal] [2023-02-13 18:35:10,942] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.exception.GlobalThrowableMapper} - Some thing went wrong while getting OAuth application for given consumer key KBs51iQITZK02v5oPwSRewK7q_Qa
```

Comment: Did you run the migration client when moving from 2.6.0 to 4.1.0?

Comment: Have you already migrated the Service provider that you are trying to map to this application? or do you want to create a service provider with a given consumer key, secret pair and map it to an application?

Comment: @Lakshitha I'm not sure what you mean by Service Provider, but we are trying to import applications through DevPortal REST API. Applications and subscriptions were successfully imported, the only issue is importing consumer key and secret pairs for each application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually application migration is covered under the migration procedure and seems like you have missed it. However you can still get this done.

Instead of this path, shall we try using the apictl project? APICTL provides the exporting and importing APIs/Applications without much hussle and there is an easy way to achieve your requirement.

1. Download the APICTL for APIM 4.1.0.
2. Create an environment with apictl pointing to your deployment, login and list the application. You can find the APICTL commands with this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/managing-applications/managing-applications/)
3. Export a created application which has consumer key, and secret generated. (`apictl export app -e dev -n <application_name> -o <app_owner> -k --with-keys`)
4. Extract the downloaded zip file and check the application.yaml
5. Export the application that doesn't have consumer key,secret generated.
6. Fill the consumer key and secret section of that applications' application.yaml. (Since this application doesn't have keys exported, you might have to copy the section from the previous exported application. That's why i asked you to export it in the 3rd step for reference)
7. Here consumer secret is base64 encoded. Therefore you need to encode it and add it here.
8. Import the updated application with `apictl import app -f dev/admin-TestAPP -e dev -k --update`. The location of the directory is given with `-f` flag.
9. This should map the consumer key secret pair to this application. (If this update does not work, you can delete the application from devportal and import this again. this will create a new application with provided consumer key secret combination).

Let me know whether this worked.

Comment: Thank you, `apictl` works. One small thing that I noticed: on step 7 you mentioned that consumeSecret is base64 encoded, secret is indeed encoded after export but on import it is not decoded back and as a result application created with encode secret, is it a bug?

Comment: I will accept this answer since it helps me with import. However question about /map-keys endpoint still open

Answer (score 1):

map-keys endpoint will not work in your requirement. When you create an application and generate keys from dev portal, internally it creates a service provider. You can see these created service providers if you logged in to carbon console (https://localhost:9443/carbon). map keys endpoint is used when you already have a service provider and you need to link the application created from the devportal to that service provider. However, in your case, you don't have such service provider in the 4.1.0 environment. I believe your requirement is to use the same clientID, and secret pair of the application used in 2.6.0 with 4.1.0. This can be done only via a migration or using hacks as I suggested above.

Note that APIM 4.1.0 does not support opaque tokens anymore and the newly created applications will return JWT tokens.

Answer (score 0):

When moving from APIM v2.6 to APIM v4.x versions, you need to use WSO2 Migration Scripts in order to migrate your data, such as consumer keys, consumer secrets, access tokens, etc.

Please follow this - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/upgrading-api-manager/ and contact us for additional support.

The other alternative would be to start a fresh deployment where you will create a new set of Applications with a new set of consumer keys and consumer secrets. APIM v4.x versions will generate JWT-based access tokens compared to APIM v2.6 Opaque access tokens. Due to this architectural changes between these major versions, you need to use WSO2 migration scripts to migrate smoothly.

Comment: Thanks. We do fresh deployment on a separate machine and automate it with Ansible. During that process, we already configured deployment.toml and installed APIs. We just need to migrate old Applications, Subscriptions and keys. To perform that migration our plan is write export script that queries WSO2 v2.6 DB directly and an import a script that uses WSO2 v4.1 DevPortal API. I will contact WSO2 team for assistance with the migration script for that part

Comment: _"APIM v4.x versions will generate JWT-based access tokens compared to APIM v2.6 Opaque access tokens"_ How does this impact.  The issue here is not migrating the access tokens, just the key/secret used to authenticate?